# Скидка в корзине: как распределить ее по товарам?

Tags: алгоритм, корзина

Есть корзина товаров, например:

1. 2 шт. товара 1 по цене 100
2. 3 шт. товара 2 по цене 50

Итого 350

К сумме заказе применяется скидка, допустим 100, но нужно эти 100 как-то разбросать по всем товарам, а не просто вычесть из стоимости.

Ну например чтобы получилось 2 шт. товара 1 по 75 и 3 шт. товара 2 по 33.

Есть мысль делить сумму скидки на кол-во групп товаров (50 на товар 1 и 50 на товар 2) и дальше подбирать, но не могу никак выразить это алгоритмически.

Comment: А почему бы не делить пропорционально стоимости товаров? Скидка 28.57%, получаем - для первой группы 57,14, для второй - 42,86...

Comment: Для начала, опишите желаемое поведение и граничные условия поточнее. Например, что если групп 20, а скидка только 10? Или вот у вас пример, вы "разбрасываете" 100, но по сумме получается +25*2+17*3 = 101, а не 100.

Comment: Желаемое поведение - получить такие цены на товары, чтобы итоговая скидка была максимально близка к заданной. Я понимаю что итог может не совпадать и плавать вокруг заданной фиксированной скидки, это нормально.

Comment: Да, спасибо, подумаю над делением пропорционально стоимости

Comment: Самый просто способ расчитать в процентах скидку и вычесть из каждого товара этот процент

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, если говорить о пропопциях, то вот например элемент корзины

```
public class BasketItem
{
    public string Product{get;set;}
    public int Quantity{get;set;}
    public double Price {get;set;}
    public double Discount{get;set;}
    public double PriceWithDiscount => Price - Discount;
}
```

Положим туда 2 товара

```
var basket = new List<BasketItem>() {
    new BasketItem(){Product = "product one", Price=100, Quantity = 2 },
    new BasketItem(){Product = "product two", Price=50, Quantity = 3 },
};
```

Общая сумма скидки

```
var totalDiscount = 100;
```

Стоимость корзины без скидки

```
var totalCost = basket.Sum(x=>x.Quantity * x.Price); // 350
```

Далее, считаем скидку для кажлого товар в корзине

```
foreach(var b in basket)
{
    var cost = b.Quantity * b.Price;  // суммарная стоимость позиции в корзине
    var percentage = cost / totalCost; // стоимость позиции относительно общей стоимости
    var discountForItem = totalDiscount * percentage; // величина скидки на всю позицию
    var discountPerProduct = discountForItem / b.Quantity; // скидка на один товар в позиции
    b.Discount = discountPerProduct; // созраняем скидку
}
```

Далее, проверяем

```
foreach (var b in basket)
    Console.WriteLine(
        $"{b.Product} price: {b.Price} disount: {b.Discount} price with discount: {b.PriceWithDiscount}");
```

Вывод

```
product one price: 100 disount: 28.5714285714286 price with discount: 71.4285714285714
product two price: 50 disount: 14.2857142857143 price with discount: 35.7142857142857
```

Полученная стоимость корзины с учетом скидки

```
Console.WriteLine(basket.Sum(x=>x.Quantity * x.PriceWithDiscount));
```

Вывод

```
250
```

Полученная стоимость ровно на 100 единиц дешевле стоимости без скидки, чего мы и добивались.

Погрешности и прочее уже посчитаете сами.